# databricks Job cluster output Limits

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am running a production job in databricks using cluster. During environment Initialization I have created a  notebook which will include lot of print statements which is causing job cluster to exceed the output size and the job was failing.

I have tried to configure this parameter

```
spark.databricks.driver.disableScalaOutput true
```

Seems to be the above parameter does not working. Is there any other way we can tackle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

> a notebook which will include lot of print statements which is causing job cluster to exceed the output size and the job was failing.

As per the given information I have tried to repro the issue by writing the 999 print per Notebook with total 3 notebooks. Means total 2997 print statements in a notebook and it is working fine for me. Please refer below image.

[image]

The possible reasons for the error could be:

- If you are using multiple display(), displayHTML(), show() commands in your notebook, this increases the amount of output. Once the output exceeds 20 MB, the error occurs.
- If you are using multiple print() commands in your notebook, this can increase the output to stdout. Once the output exceeds 20 MB, the error occurs.
- If you are running a streaming job and enable `awaitAnyTermination` in the cluster’s Spark config, it tries to fetch the entire output in a single request. If this exceeds 20 MB, the error occurs.

So, make sure the total output shouldn’t exceed 20 MB.

**Solution:**

Remove any unnecessary `display()`, `displayHTML()`, `print()`, and `show()`, commands in your notebook. **These can be useful for debugging, but they are not recommended for production jobs**.

If your job output is exceeding the 20 MB limit, try redirecting your logs to log4j or disable stdout by setting `spark.databricks.driver.disableScalaOutput` true in the cluster’s Spark config.

Comment: have you tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161733/databricks-sql-how-to-get-all-the-rows-more-than-1000-in-the-first-run

Comment: @utkarsh Are you running this  as a job ? I tried configuring with this parameter but still it is failing .

Comment: I'm just simply running the Notebook and tried to repro the issue. Running fine for me. Have you tried after dropping all `print()` statements?

Comment: Runnig as a individual notebook wonot be an issue. but inside a job it will limit the output.